# Make variable reference its own string content

Tags: string, perl, reference

I wanted to make a variable reference its own content so I did this:

```
$x=\$x;
```

but that does not work as I expected, `$x` became a reference to itself so `$$x` is the same as `$x`. What I was expecting is that `$$x` becomes the original string.  Why is that and how should I write it correctly without making a copy of the string in `$x`? Because in some cases `$x` can be a huge string.

Comment: Even if you could do what you were trying to do, the original content would be gone because of reference counting. Just use a different variable for the reference.

Comment: @AKHolland oh, right... I did not think of the reference counting...

Comment: @AKHolland, Nonsense. It can't be gone if it's still accessible. If the OP could do what they are trying to do (access the original value as `$$x`), then it would be a major bug in Perl if its reference count had reached zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking is impossible. A variable can't contain both a reference and a string. You must utilize two variables. This leaves you with two options.

**Store the reference in a new variable**

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   my $x = "abc";
   my $y = \$x;
   say $y;
   say $$y;
'
SCALAR(0x232a398)
abc
```

Nice and simple, efficient, and no confusion as to what the variable contains at what time.

The downside of this approach is that references to the original `$x` won't see the change. It's hard to imagine a situation where this would matter, however.

Note that the new var could even have the same name as the old one. I don't recommend this as it's needlessly confusing and error-prone.

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   my $x = "abc";
   my $x = \$x;
   say $x;
   say $$x;
'
SCALAR(0x232a398)
abc
```

**Store the value in a new variable**

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   my $x = "abc";
   $x = \( my $container = $x );
   say $x;
   say $$x;
'
SCALAR(0x175cbe0)
abc
```

The downside of this approach is it involves copying the string. However, that's only the case until 5.20. 5.20 introduced a copy-on-write mechanism for strings. That means the above won't actually copy the string in 5.20+; it will just copy a pointer instead. Note that both scalars share the same string buffer (`0x2ac53d0`) in the following example:

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'my $x = "abc"; my $y = $x; Dump($_) for $x, $y;' 2>&1 \
   | grep -P '^(?:SV|  FLAGS|  PV)\b'
SV = PV(0x2a9f0c0) at 0x2abcdc8
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x2ac53d0 "abc"\0
SV = PV(0x2a9f150) at 0x2abcde0
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x2ac53d0 "abc"\0
```

While `$x = \"$x"` has been suggested as a shorter version of `$x = \( my $container = $x );`, it forces stringification, and it copies the entire string, even in versions of Perl that support COW.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a reference to the value, not to the variable:

```
my $string = 'abcefgh';
$string = \ "$string";

print $$string, "\n";
```

Comment: But wouldn't this make a copy of the string? Wouldn't "abcefgh" and "$string" exist in the same time?

Comment: @soger: So create it right at the beginning: `my $string = \ 'abcdefgh';`.

Comment: real life is not that simple.

Comment: @soger: What is wrong with duplicating the string? Short of writing some C code it is the only way to get a reference to the variable's *content* instead of to the variable itself. I can't see it being a problem unless the string holds multiple gigabytes.

Comment: You copy the value, but need to just get reference to it. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46325686/1336858

Comment: @ikegami You are wrong here. choroba does "$value", not just $value, so optimization will not be applied. AFAIK.

Comment: @Akzhan Abdulin, You are right that I was wrong. I didn't realize `\"$x"` had been used. COW does not (currently) come into play in that situation (although it should). Comment deleted.

Comment: `$string = \ "$string";` is similar to `$string = \( my $anon = $string );` except the former forces stringification, and actually does copy the string (unlike the latter in newer versions of Perl).